# CouchDB view to emit docs where doc element is a particular type

Tags: couchdb

I'm new to couch, but I'm tracking down a bug and would like a view that will emit all docs of a certain type where the value of a certain key is not an array.

I tried

```
function(doc) {
    if( doc.Type == "MyType" && !( doc.Stuff instanceof Array ) )
    {
         emit( doc._id, null );
    }
}
```

But it's returning all the docs of type "MyType" even though doc.Stuff is an Array.  Is what I want to do possible?  Am I just making a stupid mistake?

For the record this is just a temporary view I'm using to hopefully track down a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
if(doc.Type === "MyType" && !isArray(doc.Stuff))
```

Comment: Great!  Thanks.  Found the bug already, but this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rely on `constructor` or anything that relies on `constructor` like `instanceof`.  I'd recommend duck typing this with something like this:

```
if( doc.Type == "MyType" && !( doc.Stuff.splice && doc.Stuff.join ) )
```